# How to use parcelable safe arg in nav_graph.xml with navigation component in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to pass a parcelable object named animation from FirstFragment to SecondFragment with safe arg. I want to use name of this animation in nav_graph.xml file for label of SecondFragment but I got this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find animation.name in Bundle.`
I don't want to pass name string separately. I want to pass animation object.
How can I do that?

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQcr0.png)

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer for mobile devices ... so take my comment with a grain of salt, but looking at the error and taking it literally, I have to ask, are you sure you are referencing the correct property of the object you are trying to pass into the SecondFragment ... AND/OR ... is that property accessible from that context? Looking at the code and not having more details, it seems like the 'animation.name' property is either not accessible from the context you're referencing it from, OR you have the name of the property wrong.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, we can override toString method in the Animation class and return its name property.
then we can put animation instead of animation.name in nav_graph.xml and it works.